Why does my daily event in AnyLogic skip days in simulation time?
In my AnyLogic model, I want to display the current weekday updated daily. I use an event configured to trigger at a rate of 1 per day. However, the display skips weekdays (e.g., jumping from Monday to Friday), as multiple days pass in simulation time between updates. The issue resolves if I set the rate to 1 per hour. Why does this happen, and how can I ensure accurate daily updates?


In my big simulation model I have multiple events that should be triggered once per day, and I have the feeling that it also does not update daily.

Your trigger type is "Rate". This is not exactly every day/hour but approximately that, with some randomness (Poission stream) put in for good measure.
Always read around the help to understand the options you set:

Set it to timeout-triggered and it will trigger like clockwork. You can easily test that using traceln("I triggered at "+time()); in the event itself
